# Upload image using jquery or javascript and image should store in my path with out php

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i took this code for file upload using jquery or javascsript in jsfiddle given below

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/d3H9f/

```
<input type='file' />
<img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" />

$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

I want to store image in my folder. but the above code show path like

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
```

but i want path like "E:\yello.png" can u help me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you are asking cannot be done via file input elements because the browser will not expose the full path to the file (a security feature). The only way this could be done is if the user entered the full path in a text input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: you can get the file name, but not the path at myImg.value or myImg.files[0].name;